# Access is denied while compiling Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows, java-7

I created two java files: `Pizza.Java` and `PizzaOrder.Java`.

I tried compiling my code using javac in the command prompt like this:

```
javac pizzaorder.java
```

**I am getting access is denied error:**

```
C:\Users\Meutex>cd\

C:\>cd "Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>javac PizzaOrder.java
PizzaOrder.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
                Pizza order = new Pizza ();
                ^
  symbol:   class Pizza
  location: class PizzaOrder
PizzaOrder.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
                Pizza order = new Pizza ();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Pizza
  location: class PizzaOrder
2 errors

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>javac Pizza.java
Pizza.java:11: error: error while writing Pizza: Pizza.class (Access is denied)
public class Pizza {
       ^
1 error

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>javac Pizza.java
```

What am I doing to cause this error?

Comment: The user on the terminal doesn't have permission to write to that directory.  So javac cannot do its work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to put your source files in the system `C:\Program Fiels\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` directory. Try making your own directory for your source files (under your own home directory), instead of putting them in the system path. You probably don't have permissions to write to that directory (but I'm not sure how you got your source files there).

Answer (score 7):

The Access Denied error is most likely due to the fact that you're trying to compile this program within the jdk directory, which is inside `\Program Files`, which is NOT universally writeable by users. You should be doing your coding elsewhere (perhaps in your `My Documents` directory, or at least somewhere you've got write permissions).

Comment: Well, if I change the path to `My Documents` how can I use javac command there?

Comment: Add the jdk directory to your system path. if it's not there already, you can do so via the 'System' control panel: System Properties -> Advanced (tab) -> Environment Variables (button).

Comment: Well, I went fine up to `Environment Variables` what's next? should I click on `new user variable` or `new system variable.`

Comment: Should be a path in both system and user sections. edit the existing path variable in the user section and add the JDK directory to it, unless you want all users to have the same new path setting.

Comment: I edited with variable name `path` and variable path `C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;` but still I am unable to use `javac` in cmd.

Comment: Make sure you open a *new* cmd window after changing the path. Changing environment variables doesn't affect cmd windows that are already open.

Comment: you'll have to open a new cmd window for the new path var to take effect. changing the var settings in the control panel won't change it in any existing windows - only new ones opened AFTER you  made the changes.

Comment: Sorry.. yeah! this fixed on re-opening cmd. Thanks a lot Greg and Marc.

Comment: BTW is it possible to run a console application in netbeans?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have permission to write in the directory. You shouldn't put your source code in the bin directory of the JDK.

Instead, add that bin directory to your `PATH` and create a work directory in your user home folder.

See [How to set the path in windows 7](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I know this has no relation with Java, but try it, it worked for me.
I realized it while I was playing with windows explorer.

1. Goto C:\Program Files\
2. Right click java folder, click properties. Select the security tab.
3. There, click on "Edit" button, which will pop up PERMISSIONS FOR JAVA window.
4. Click on Add, which will pop up a new window. In that, in the "Enter object name" box, Enter your user account name, and click okay(if already exist, skip this step).
5. Now in "PERMISSIONS OF JAVA" window, you will see several clickable options like CREATOR OWNER, SYSTEM, among them is your username. Click on it, and check mark the FULL CONTROL option in Permissions for  sub window.
6. Finally, Hit apply and okay.

This should be it. You will now be able to compile as well as run your java programs right there in the bin, instead of doing other things.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you need to do is to run your cmd as administrator. So right click on cmd and run as administrator. That should solve your problems!

Answer (score -1):

U need to set ur path in ur computer.first copy of ur bin path(c:/programfiles/java/jdk1.7/bin) then go to ur computer properties->advanced system settings->Environment variables then click new then type path in name and paste it with semicolons front and back(;c:/programfiles/java/jdk1.7/bin;).... then it will run.....

Answer (score -3):

***Solved in easy way***                                                                                        Just run ***cmd* as "Administrator"**
If u are using IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse there no problem at all..