# Java application cannot write/read serialization file when installed to C:/Program Files - java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied)

Tags: java, serialization, installation, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

My app uses this code to persistently save an ArrayList so it can be recalled when the app is restarted.

```
    private static void storeDevices() {
    // Object serialization
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("devices.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(devices);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        showAlert("Store Devices", "Exception storing devices to file: " + e);
    } 
}
```

Everything works fine when I run from Netbeans. I have wrapped the app in an installer (using Launch4J and Inno Setup Compiler) and when I install the app to C:/Program Files/MyApp (on Windows 7) the above code gives the following exception:

> Exception storing devices to file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: devices.ser (Access is denied)

However, when I install to C:/MyApp, everything works fine.

Is this something to do with read/write permission being inherited from the C:/Program Files directory? I know I may be able to solve this be creating the file in C:/temp directory or somewhere like that but I don't want to have to resort to that. So is there any way I can write/read files in my C:/Program Files/MyApp directory?

Comment: try installing with "Run as Administrator"

Comment: I think this problem got discussed in a older question look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865160/java-error-while-writing-access-is-denied

Comment: I don't really want to Run as Administrator - I want keep this as normal/correct as possible. The other SO link didn't help either. But thank you both anyway.

Comment: Maybe I'm going around this the wrong way. I've just discovered the Preferences API - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-prefapi/index.html - which sounded promising, but it does not recommend using Serializable objects with it, so am hoping there is a better solution??

Comment: Maybe using environment variables would be a good way to get the correct directory to store application data - e.g. System.getenv("ALLUSERSPROFILE") or System.getenv("APPDATA") - but are these cross-platform??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use environment variables to get the correct directory to store application data. Here's the method I created:

```
private String getAppDataDirectory(String subDirectory, boolean create) {

    String appDataDirectory;
    try {
        appDataDirectory = System.getenv("APPDATA"); //Windows
        //todo - could try "ALLUSERSPROFILE"
        if (appDataDirectory != null) {
            appDataDirectory += File.separator + subDirectory + File.separator;
        }
        else { //appDataDirectory is null
            appDataDirectory = System.getenv("HOME"); //Unix
            if (appDataDirectory != null) {
                appDataDirectory +=  File.separator + subDirectory + File.separator;
            }
            else { //appDataDirectory is still null
                throw new Exception("Could not access APPDATA or HOME environment variables");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        appDataDirectory = "";
    }

    if (create && appDataDirectory != null && appDataDirectory.length() > 0) {
        try {
            File dir = new File(appDataDirectory);
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //log("appDataDirectory: " + appDataDirectory);
    return appDataDirectory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from windows vista onward, no app can access system folder area without explicit authentication. (folders like program-file/window32/ etc....)
For installed app, authentication is done by windows-installer.

To be able to access (read/write) either you need to run as administrator, or you need to change permission of those folder (which is not recommended)