# Java applet compile time error

Tags: java, applet

When compiling this code from the command prompt

```
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.*;  
public class Main extends Applet{    
    public void paint(Graphics g){       
        g.drawString("Welcome in Java Applet.",40,20);    
    } 
}
```

I get the error `Access denied`.

Comment: and how you are running this code ??

Comment: I am running this code on command prompt like this: 
    javac Main.java

Comment: Error shown: Main.java:4: error while writing Main:Main.class (Access is denied)

Comment: Welcome to SO @Saksahm Arora!  You will want to include the entire text of the exception.  Also please see [this report of a similar problem(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865160/access-is-denied-while-compiling-java-on-windows) and [this report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341368/java-compile-error-helloworldapp-it-shows-error-while-writing-and-access-d).  If you are on Windows it appears you may not have full write access to the directory in which the class files are trying to go.  Are you running the command session with administrator privileges?

Comment: @SakshamArora where you are putting your code??

Comment: Turns out I wasn't running command prompt in administrator mode which is why it was not able to publish Main.class in the C directory, where my Main.java was stored. Thanks @eebbesen

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to put your source files in the `Java/jdk/bin` directory. Try to make your own directory for your source files in `different drive or folder`, instead of putting them in the `system path`.

You might be not having permission.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it to a folder where you know you have write access:

```
javac -d "C:\Temp" Main.java
```